# hash_hmac (PHP) vs hex_hmac_sha1 (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php

Im new here and I have question.

Could you tell me why **hex_hmac_sha1** (function in Javascript) is not working as well as **hash_hmac** (function in PHP).

If it's A-z letter its all ok but its not ok for other characters.

For example:

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://online.ingbank.pl/mobi/js/sha1.js"></script>
<script>
document.write(hex_hmac_sha1("1492343027",'a')+"<br />");
document.write(hex_hmac_sha1("1492343027",'ą')+"<br />");
document.write(hex_hmac_sha1("1492343027",'c')+"<br />");
document.write(hex_hmac_sha1("1492343027",'ć')+"<br />");
</script>
```

output:

```
f75d4cbfbfda2476a9c92fff10fdf0e726ee06ab
206e608ecaf23a9575ca81a86e3afd72eca243a0
73e0dc1dd914b1386a5f2624883caad41025da07
86dc107aac5cb5c17a846defd651a3eb53d66a44
```

**PHP**

```
echo hash_hmac("sha1", 'a', "1492343027").'<br />'; 
echo hash_hmac("sha1", 'ą', "1492343027").'<br />'; 
echo hash_hmac("sha1", 'c', "1492343027").'<br />'; 
echo hash_hmac("sha1", 'ć', "1492343027").'<br />';
```

output:

```
f75d4cbfbfda2476a9c92fff10fdf0e726ee06ab
8b353bb4c891d73ae9be09d0653e2564e0dff243
73e0dc1dd914b1386a5f2624883caad41025da07
52278a6e8676e8f3c667082411cfa04519c4bab1
```

For 'a' and 'c' its all ok but what is going on with 'ą' and 'ć'?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the PHP and JS implementation is, that PHP handles the UTF-8 string as as 8-bit chars, while in JS each char is represented by Unicode.

Please give this a try:

`hash_hmac("sha1", 'ą', "1492343027") == hex_hmac_sha1("1492343027",'\xC4\x85')`

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/appcs92g/)**

UTF 8 hex from - http://www.charbase.com/0105-unicode-latin-small-letter-a-with-ogonek

**JS**

```
hex_hmac_sha1("1492343027",'ą')        = 206e608ecaf23a9575ca81a86e3afd72eca243a0
hex_hmac_sha1("1492343027",'\xC4\x85') = 8b353bb4c891d73ae9be09d0653e2564e0dff243
```

Escape your Unicode on JS side...

**PHP**

```
hash_hmac("sha1", 'ą', "1492343027");        = 8b353bb4c891d73ae9be09d0653e2564e0dff243
hash_hmac("sha1", "\xC4\x85", "1492343027"); = 8b353bb4c891d73ae9be09d0653e2564e0dff243
```

Comment: It's working of course but I want to get sth like this:

hex_hmac_sha1("1492343027",'ą') == hash_hmac("sha1", $x , "1492343027")

what $x should be?

hex_hmac_sha1 function results are ok, php is problem for me

Comment: No - you are not looking for this :) Escape your ą on JS side!

Comment: Im working in curl and I must play all from javascript in php so I can't escape my ą on JS side :(

Comment: I want to get 206e608ecaf23a9575ca81a86e3afd72eca243a0 value by hash_hmac function

Comment: Then escape your ą on PHP side for transfer to the JS side. As you can see, the escaped version works on both sides...

Comment: I know its working but site ingbank.pl works only with no escaped version and when I'm using curl I must send required content and its base on hex_hmac_sha1 from https://online.ingbank.pl/mobi/js/sha1.js and it can't be modified on js side

Comment: **1)** Man, how sad is this. It's a multi-million dollar banking website. They should provide decent developer documentation. If not, contact them, to improve that! They should provide a login example for copy/paste for working with their API.

Comment: **2)** Are you sure, that special chars are in the range of allowed chars?

Comment: **3)** what you could do is, simply save the sha1.js next to your php script and write a custom webpage using it on your side. then make an extra request to that, to calculate the hash (on your side). that should be the expected hash by the banking site itself. this solution is also used in https://github.com/ecikowaty/INGBankOnlineClient/blob/master/AccountInfoProvider.cpp#L157 .

Comment: Hello again, thank for help, surely SHA-1 works like you said but this sha1.js script works otherwise, I cant pass js variables and php variables in normal way so I decided to rewrite this script in PHP function by function so thanks again.